# How to trigger stage B only when stage A fails in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two stages in a jenkins Pipeline.
Stage A and then Stage B.
I would like to trigger stage B only if stage A fails. If stage A is successful then skip stage B.
How can I achieve this one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below:

```
def stageA_Fail = false

pipeline {
 stages {
   stage('A') {
     steps {
       script {
         try {
            // put all steps of stage A in try
         }
         catch() {
           stageA_Fail = true
         }
       }
     }
   }
 
   stage('B') {
     when {expression {return stageA_Fail} }
     steps {}
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use try and catch block, and put stage B in catch block. You need to catch the error/exception though

Comment: I'm using declarative pipeline. I don't think we can use try catch in that .

Comment: sure, then there is a when condition which you can make use of, define a variable, set that to true in catch block and use that as a conditional step in stage B